# Foundation Float Grid broken by input-group

Tags: css, css-float, zurb-foundation

Using Zurb Foundation 6.3.1, I display elements using the `Float Grid`. Unfortunately, also using the class `input-group` looks to break the style because of the `display: table` used in this class.

Here is what is rendered (3 first RGB inputs are with the `input-group` style, the other one are without it):

[image]

As you can see, the green input won't go on the left. The `end`class make it go on the left of the blue input only, like if the red input was reserving the space.

Here's the CSS from Foundation `input-group` class:

```
.input-group {
    display: if($global-flexbox, flex, table);
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: $form-spacing;

    @if $global-flexbox {
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    > :first-child {
      border-radius: if($global-text-direction == rtl, 0 $input-radius $input-radius 0, $input-radius 0 0 $input-radius);
    }

    > :last-child {
      > * {
        border-radius: if($global-text-direction == rtl, $input-radius 0 0 $input-radius, 0 $input-radius $input-radius 0);
      }
    }
}
```

My HTML code:

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="title">Foundation Design</h3>

        <!-- With the input-group class -->
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="large-6 column">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-label"></span>
                    <input class="input-group-field typo-small" type="text" style="background-color: red;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 column">
                <input type="text" style="background-color: blue;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 column end">
                <input type="text" style="background-color: green;"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Without the input-group class -->
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="large-6 column">
                <div class=""> <!-- Fine without the .input-class styling -->
                    <span class="input-group-label"></span>
                    <input class="input-group-field typo-small" type="text" style="background-color: red;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-6 column">
                <input type="text" style="background-color: blue;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 column end">
                <input type="text" style="background-color: green;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone ever experienced this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input-group` has a bottom margin of 1 rem. But because this is rendered within a table, it apparently causes an extra pixel. That's why the green bar doesn't float to the left.

To fix this, I would simply overwrite the `input-group` with `margin-bottom: 0;` and all is well.

Comment: Many thanks to you! Indeed, adding `style="margin-bottom: 0;"` to the div did the trick, and now, everything is perfectly aligned! Thank you once again!